# Number of access points for wifi fingerprinting

Tags: wifi, fingerprinting, access-point

I'm making project for positioning using WiFi fingerprint , but the building I'm testing the project in has only 3 access point that covers the whole building(the building is 5 floors),
Is the 3 access point are enough or not and how many access points I need to do the WiFi fingerprinting ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "it depends". Two major considerations:

1. How well does RF propagate through this building? (lots of wiring, steel & concrete, or mainly wood frame & drywall)
2. How precise do your positioning tools need to be?

Typically, additional Access Points can reduce the likelihood of deadspots and variation due to changes in environmental factors, and improve precision. If you are able to test your fingerprinting system before it is implemented, you should be able to determine whether 3 access points will be sufficient. Likely, for a steel/concrete commercial building with 5 floors, you'll want additional access points for better coverage. What number will you need? It depends on your answers to #1 and #2.

For further discussion, see the paper "[Indoor Location Using Trilateration Characteristics](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/lcs/previous/LCS2005/12.pdf)"